# How to add API key confidentially inside config map?

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I am new to K8s. I am trying to deploy a Datadog agent to my cluster to collect logs and this happens through a ConfigMap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-cm
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Parsers_File     parsers.conf
    
    [INPUT]
        name              tail
        path              /tmp/app.log
        parser            nginx

    [OUTPUT]
        Name           datadog
        Match          *
        Host           http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com
        TLS            off
        apikey         <API key to be used confidentially>
        dd_service     abcd
        dd_source      abcd
        dd_tags        env:dev

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name   nginx
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*))" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"(?: "(?<target>[^\"]*))"$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
```

I do not want to add the API key as plain text. Can I do it using secrets? Please suggest ways to achieve this.

P.S: I need to use the config map in order to add the Datadog agent, and hence the config map cannot be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could [Secret as a environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables), and pass it to a Pod using ConfigMap.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: fluentbit-secret-test
type: Opaque
data:
  apikey: <base64 encoded api key>
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-cm
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |
...
        apikey         $FLUENTBIT_API_KEY
...
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: nginx
    env:
      - name: FLUENTBIT_API_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: fluentbit-secret-test
            key: apikey
```

However, you must remember, that Kubernetes Secrets are not encrypted by default, only base64 encoded. Anyone with API access can retrieve or modify a Secret, and so can anyone with access to etcd

Comment: I tried this exactly but it's not working. any changes you suggest